# Отсутствует перевод на странице, которая не найдена

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На небезызвестной странице [404](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547110/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-error-expected-before-b?noredirect=1) в некоторых местах отсутствует перевод:

[image: 404]

Ещё и точка с лишним пробелом.

Comment: Давно зарепортили, но воз и ныне там.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так может правили, а потом менялись английские строки и все слетало :-)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, тогда про точечку не забудьте :)

Comment: @Grundy типа перевели туда-сюда-обратно?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, о ... и резолюция о дубликатности тоже без перевода .. хе-хе `This question was marked as an exact duplicate`.

Comment: @alexolut где такое? я везде вижу переведенные строки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну прямо на этой же странице.