# Отсутствие перевода о закрытии вопроса как дубликата

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Отсутствие перевода о закрытие [вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3425/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) как дубликата, причем как выяснилось в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31192513#31192513), перевод отсутствует только для автора сообщения.

[image: дубликат]

[Tx:8433](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/80722931?key=1579af725ce9618f321d3d7c5fec9f4a)

> This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question. If this question is different, please `[edit it]($editUrl$)` to explain how it is different or `[ask a new question]($askUrl$)`.

Comment: Предлагайте варианты перевода )

Comment: Прошлые варианты этой же строки: https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262820?qt=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5

Comment: @NickVolynkin у меня нет аккаунта транзифекса до сих пор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. сообщение показывается только автору, можно перевести так:

> Ваш вопрос отмечен как полный дубликат существующего вопроса. Если вы считаете, что ваш вопрос отличается от существующего, пожалуйста, [отредактируйте] его, чтобы прояснить это или [задайте новый вопрос].